# Which one is preferable between "irse a + infinitive" and "hacerse + infinitive"?

Tags: gramática

I have come across ([here](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/make-me-blush.638966/)) at least 2 different ways of translating *to someone do something*, one involves **irse** and the other **hacerse**. Let's take the following example:

> *You make me blush.*
>
> **Me vas a sonrojar.**
>
> **Me haces sonrojar.**

My question is, which of the above two constructs enjoys better currency in the streets? If there's a regional preference, what do the Mexicans or Latin Americans prefer? Also, is there any other translation that is preferred over either of the two? I have also come across **me pones sonrojo**. Is the **poner** construct preferable if the second verb (*blush* in this case) can be expressed as an adjective?

Comment: Although I speak peninsular Spanish, I'm reasonably certain that —barring some significant dialectal difference— *me vas a sonrojar* and *me haces sonrojar* are universally not equivalent (the former uses the verb *ir* with the verb *sonrojar(le)* and the latter *hacer(le)* with the verb *sonrojar*), but *me pones sonroja* would be very close in meaning in effective meaning to the latter.

Comment: In Argentina is very common the use of "me hacés poner colorado", which is the same as saying "Me haces sonrojar". Also, I agree with guifa in that the two constructs are different. One last thing: where did you come across with "me pones sonroja"?

Comment: In Spain we would say more or less as @PiQ says, but with a twist: *me voy a poner colorado*. On the other hand, *me pones sonroja* is incorrect, as far as I know. *Sonroja* is not a noun or adjective that I've ever heard.

Comment: @Gorpik maybe it's _sonrojá_, as we Andalusians would pronounce _sonrojada_. Or maybe it's a typo.

Comment: Updated the question with a link to where I found the translations and also corrected **sonroja** to **sonrojo**. Is **me vas sonrojar** (without the preposition) a possibility? If so, how common is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Me vas a sonrojar.** *This is future, not happened already*

**Me haces sonrojar.** *This is present, you already do it*

**Me pones sonrojar.** *Never listened that. But "Me pones roja" o "Me voy  a poner roja" it's used too, and means the same as the other two. First in present, and second in future.*

Both are usually used and are correct, but I think in latin America they used the word "colorado" instead of sonrojado.

**Me voy a poner colorada** *Future, referring to something happened*

**Me vas a poner colorada** *Future, referring something you do*

**Me estoy poniendo colorada** *Present*

Comment: En España yo empleo indistintamente la palabra colorado y sonrojado

Comment: +1 for the crisp explanation. Just one question: Is **me vas sonrojar** (without the preposition) a possibility? If so, how common is it?

Comment: @TheLearner No, "me vas sonrojar" isn't a possibility, you need the preposition.